# Moving files not woking in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a code:

```
cls
$folderPath = 'Y:\lit\Retail\abc\abc\FTP-FromClient\AMS\2022-03-23'
$files = Get-ChildItem $folderPath
$destination='Y:\lit\Retail\abc\abc\FTP-FromClient\AMS\2022-03-23\bz2'
$leftfiles=('20220322054419',
'20220322083959',
'20220322084715',
'20220322085207',
'20220322085250',
'20220322085858',
'20220322090236',
'20220322090410',
'20220322090450'
'20220322170306')

foreach($j in $leftfiles)
{
    foreach($f in $files) 
    {
        if ($f -contains $j)
        {
            Move-Item $f.FullName $destination
        }
    }
}
```

In this $folderPath I have some files:

```
$folderPath = 'Y:\lit\Retail\abc\abc\FTP-FromClient\AMS\2022-03-23'
```

File naming has some naming convention as which matches with the numbers inside the aray:

```
Colly_20220322054419.dat.bz2
Colly_1_20220322084715.dat.bz2
Colly_3_20220322085207.dat
```

I only need to move all the files to the `destination` ,if **filename** contains the **number inside array elements.** So I tried using `-contains` to move the file but it's not working:

```
foreach($j in $leftfiles)
{
    foreach($f in $files) 
    {
        if ($f -contains $j)
        {
            Move-Item $f.FullName $destination
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code could be simplified if you use a `Where-Object` clause that filters the files to move using the regex `-match` operator

```
$folderPath  = 'Y:\lit\Retail\abc\abc\FTP-FromClient\AMS\2022-03-23'
$destination = 'Y:\lit\Retail\abc\abc\FTP-FromClient\AMS\2022-03-23\bz2'
$leftfiles   = '20220322054419', '20220322083959','20220322084715','20220322085207','20220322085250',
               '20220322085858','20220322090236','20220322090410','20220322090450','20220322170306'

# first make sure the destination folder exists
$null = New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory -Force

# join the items from $leftfiles with a pipe symbol (=the regex 'OR')
$regex = $leftfiles -join '|'

Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -File |
Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match $regex } |
Move-Item -Destination $destination
```

<sup>If you want to test this out first, append switch `-WhatIf` to the `Move-Item` line. THat way, nothing actually gets moved. Only in the console, it is displayed what *would be moved*</sup>